# Send multiple select form as an array with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, select

Currently I'm posting single values from some multiple select boxes. If I want to post the variables as arrays on the field activity and yearOfBirth instead of strings, how can I achieve this by changing my current code?

Thanks!

```
function showUser() {
    // getting the value that user typed
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var sex = $("#sex").val();
    var registrationType = $("#registrationType").val();
    var activity = $("#activity").val();
    var yearOfBirth = $("#yearOfBirth").val();

    // forming the queryString
    var data = 'search_firstName=' + firstName + '&search_lastName=' + lastName + '&search_registrationType=' + registrationType + '&search_activity=' + activity + '&search_yearOfBirth=' + yearOfBirth + '&search_sex=' + sex;

    // if searchString is not empty
    if (firstName || lastName || sex || registrationType || activity || yearOfBirth) {
        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "groupQsearchMember.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#whileLoading').show();
                $('#results').hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#whileLoading').hide();
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $("#results").html(html);
                $("#results").fadeIn(700);
            },

        });
    }
    return false;
};​
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the value of the select fields into an array, simply add `.split(',')`, then iterating over the array to add the array brackets, for example:

```
var registrationTypeString = "";
$("#registrationType").val().split(',').each(function(item){
    registrationTypeString += '&registrationType[]=' + item;
});

//..

var data = 'search_firstName=' + firstName + '&search_lastName=' + lastName + registrationTypeString + '&search_activity=' + activity + '&search_yearOfBirth=' + yearOfBirth + '&search_sex=' + sex;
```

Do this with your select fields then you will have arrays in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to change as you described, but the page that handles the post says that firstName is now undefined. Do I have to do something else to catch the variable while using JSON?

This is what I use.

$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_firstName']);

Comment: I did some research and I don't know if this is what I want. I do not want all the values put in an array. Just the for example one or two of them. Is this still the way to go?

yearOfBirth may contain several values from the select form, the firstName will always be one value.

Comment: I just saw that PHP does not understand JSON naturally. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, however I'm unable to get it to work.

When I'm posting the variable and trying to work with it, I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I'm trying to only echo the variable which I though should echo "Array", but I'm just getting this error.

Comment: have you tried the command `print_r($_POST['registrationType'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the POST data manually, make sure your form elements have the desired `name` attribute and create `data` like this:

```
 var data = $("#firstName, #lastName, #sex, #registrationType, #activity, #yearOfBirth").serialize();
```

Which, according to [jQuery docs for `serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will create **"a text string in standard URL-encoded notation."**